# How can I redirect a stream based in an "internal state"

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I'm writing a plugin for gulp that uses a web service and depending on the response do one or other thing. The algorithm is something like this:

```
stream1 = through.obj(function(src, enc, cb) {
 if src.is_a_buffer()
     http_request(options)
     http_request.on('response', function () {
        if (statusCode = 200) {
            /* Normal course, everything works fine here */
            do_something()
            return cb()
        } else {
            /* Exception course, although the stream2 is created, is never executed */
            stream1.pipe(stream2())
        }

}, function (cb) {
    cb()
});

stream2 = through.obj(function(src,enc,cb) {
     do_other_stuff()
     stream2.push(src)
     return cb()
}, function (cb) {
    cb()
});
```

When I run the code stream2 never excecutes.
Since i'm new to node streams, I think i misunderstood something. Can any of you guys help me out understanding what am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Is this supposed to be plain javascript or a language that transpiles to javascript? If it's the former, then having an assignment where the right-hand value is `return <value>` is not valid javascript ...

Comment: @mscdex my bad. Already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `stream1.pipe(stream2())`, `stream1` has already emitted data (possibly all of it); making that call won't pass the execution on to `stream2`.  There are a couple of ways this can be handled depending on your needs:

*NOTE: I'm just modifying the original pseudocode here*

**Option 1:**

Don't bother with a `stream2` and just call `do_other_stuff()` directly:

```
stream1 = through.obj(function(src, enc, cb) {
 if src.is_a_buffer()
     http_request(options)
     http_request.on('response', function () {
        if (statusCode = 200) {
            /* Normal course, everything works fine here */
            do_something()
            cb()
        } else {
            do_other_stuff()
            cb()
        }

}, function (cb) {
    cb()
});
```

**Option 2:**

If you need `stream2` for other purposes, pull the `through.obj()` callback out in to its own callable function and call it directly from your else clause.

```
stream1 = through.obj(function(src, enc, cb) {
 if src.is_a_buffer()
     http_request(options)
     http_request.on('response', function () {
        if (statusCode = 200) {
            /* Normal course, everything works fine here */
            do_something()
            return cb()
        } else {
            processStream2(src, enc, cb)
        }

}, function (cb) {
    cb()
});

function processStream2(src, enc, cb) {
     do_other_stuff()
     return cb()
}

stream2 = through.obj(processStream2, function (cb) {
    cb()
});
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: The second option fits exactly in my scenario, and now seems so simple :D. I just needed a transformation function that can be shared among streams. Thank you!